# Is there a Trello Share URL?

Tags: url, share, trello

I was wondering if there is an URL on Trello where I can post some text from other app (without using API) - something like Facebook share URL.

For example:

`https://trello.com/share?title=New+Task&text=Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet`

would show me my boards and lists where to put new card into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES there is:

`https://trello.com/add-card?name=Hello%20World&desc=this%20works`

just pass `name` and `desc` as query parameters.